# Proxmox Additional IP Address

Tags: networking, proxmox

So, I've managed to get my subnet to work however I can not get a single additional IP to work

I'm new to this, so not sure exactly the best way to do stuff, if what I've done is wrong.

Here's my interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
    address [main-ip]
    gateway [gateway]
    pointopoint [gateway]

iface eno1 inet6 static
    address [ipv6-addr]/128
    gateway [ipv6-gateway]
    up sysctl -p

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address [subnet-ip]/28
    bridge-ports none
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
#Subnet

iface vmbr0 inet6 static
    address [ipv6-addr]/64
    up ip -6 route add [ipv6-subnet]/64 dev vmbr0

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
    address 10.0.0.1/24
    bridge-ports none
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
#LAN

auto vmbr2
iface vmbr2 inet static
    address [additional-ip]/24
    bridge-ports none
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
# Additional IP
```

Answer (score 0):

In **vmbrX** interfaces you should have **bridge-ports** mapped to physical interfaces and that **vmbrX** interface set IP static IP address

For example

```
iface **eno1** inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 192.168.10.2/24
        gateway 192.168.10.1
        **bridge-ports eno1**
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
```

https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Network_Configuration#_default_configuration_using_a_bridge

[image]